# crypto-js trouble with index.html (Angular 2 project)

Tags: html, angular, typescript, sha256, cryptojs

I used the following command to get crypto-js into my node_modules folder

```
npm install crypto-js
```

Then, after I had it downloaded, within my index.html file I use the following command so that I can call the CryptoJS.SHA256() method.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="node_modules/crypto-js/sha256"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

(I left out the other script calls, meta and title tags)

However when I run my project using 'npm start', I get the following errors

[image]

What exactly does this mean? I am not sure how to solve something that is 'not found' even though it is where is should be. Am I maybe missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

Your using external javascript that is not exposed to angular.  Only the web dom is aware of the crypto js module. It looks like you just want to use SHA256.  I would just implement a type script version of the function and go from there.  Here is an example.

https://github.com/dchest/fast-sha256-js